# How to properly link CADisplayLink with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I am creating some animation and for smoothness on various devices I use CADisplayLink like this:

```
// DisplayLink.swift
import SwiftUI

class DisplayLink: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var frameDuration: CFTimeInterval = 0
    @Published var frameChange: Bool = false
    
    static let sharedInstance: DisplayLink = DisplayLink()
    
    func createDisplayLink() {
        let displaylink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(frame))
        displaylink.add(to: .current, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
    }
    
    @objc func frame(displaylink: CADisplayLink) {
        frameDuration = displaylink.targetTimestamp - displaylink.timestamp
        frameChange.toggle()
    }
    
}
```

Then I initialize it once in the application:

```
// App.swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct App: App {
    init() {
        DisplayLink.sharedInstance.createDisplayLink()
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            CircleView()
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it throughout the application as follows:

```
// CircleView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct CircleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var displayLink = DisplayLink.sharedInstance
    //
    var body: some View {
       // 
       .onChange(of: displayLink.frameChange) { _ in
              print(displayLink.frameDuration)
           }
    }
```

Everything works great, but how correct is it to use this approach? Perhaps SwiftUI has ready-made methods for this?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I've used `CADisplayLink` in a SwiftUI project and your strategy looks okay to me. I think you just update whatever properties you want SwiftUI to watch (using the `@Published` paradigm) in your `frame(displayLink:)`, and then reference those properties in your views (I used `@EnvironmentObject`).

Comment: Yes, the idea is that. In the case of using @EnvironmentObject, the data will only be available within a specific View, as far as I understand, and not in the entire application.

Comment: Well, you can actually inject the environment object into your primary view (your `ContentView`, presumably), and then it's available to all sub-views of `ContentView`. So, I set `environmentObject(_:)` once, in my `SceneDelegate`'s `scene(_ :willConnectTo:options:)` function.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you are going to use the singleton pattern (which I wouldn’t recommend in this case), the Swift convention is to call it `shared`. We called it `sharedInstance` in Objective-C, but in Swift, it is generally simply `shared`.

Answer (score 8):

A few observations:

1. At the very least, I would consider marking this with [`@MainActor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor/), as it needs to be on a [`RunLoop`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/) (which generally means [`RunLoop.main`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/1418388-main)). Be wary of using `RunLoop.current` outside of code explicitly isolated to the `@MainActor`. If you do not explicitly specify the main actor, if you accidentally start it from anything other asynchronous context, it may silently fail. With `@MainActor`, the compiler will warn us of incorrect usage.
2. I would not personally advise making this a singleton.
3. You want to make sure you have a mechanism to [`invalidate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink/1621293-invalidate) the display link when you are done with it.

---

In a more advanced observation, a more natural pattern might be an asynchronous sequence, an [`AsyncSequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncsequence/), or, more specifically an [`AsyncStream`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncstream):

```swift
//
//  CADisplayLink+Sequence.swift
//
//  Created by Robert Ryan on 2/20/23.
//

import UIKit

@MainActor
extension CADisplayLink {
    static func events() -> AsyncStream<CADisplayLink> {
        AsyncStream { continuation in
            let displayLink = DisplayLink { displayLink in
                continuation.yield(displayLink)
            }

            continuation.onTermination = { _ in
                Task { await displayLink.stop() }
            }
        }
    }
}

// There is no need to expose this, so let's put it in a private extension

private extension CADisplayLink {
    @MainActor
    private class DisplayLink: NSObject {
        private var displayLink: CADisplayLink!
        private let handler: (CADisplayLink) -> Void

        init(mode: RunLoop.Mode = .default, handler: @escaping (CADisplayLink) -> Void) {
            self.handler = handler
            super.init()

            displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(handle(displayLink:)))
            displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: mode)
        }

        func stop() {
            displayLink.invalidate()
        }

        @objc func handle(displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
            handler(displayLink)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do things like:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var timestamp: CFTimeInterval = 0

    var body: some View  {
        VStack {
            Text("\(timestamp, specifier: "%0.2f")")
                .monospacedDigit()
        }
        .task {
            for await event in CADisplayLink.events() {
                timestamp = event.targetTimestamp
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, when this view is dismissed, the [`.task {…}`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack/task(priority:_:)) modifier is automatically canceled for us, thereby automatically canceling our asynchronous sequence, too.

If you aren't using the `.task` modifier, you have to cancel your asynchronous sequence yourself, e.g.:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View  {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.string)
                .monospacedDigit()

            Button("Start") {
                viewModel.start()
            }

            Button("Stop") {
                viewModel.stop()
            }
        }
        .onDisappear {
            viewModel.stop()
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var string = "Not running"

    private var task: Task<Void, Never>?

    private var formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SS"
        return formatter
    }()

    func start() {
        task?.cancel()

        task = Task {
            for await _ in CADisplayLink.events() {
                string = formatter.string(from: Date())
            }
        }
    }

    func stop() {
        task?.cancel()
        task = nil
    }
}
```

For more information on asynchronous sequences, see WWDC 2021 video [Meet AsyncSequence](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10058/).

Comment: Thank You! This was very helpful for a game I'm working on.

Answer (score 2):

I like your solution - it works well.  This is an alternative with a closure instead of @Published.

```
class DisplayLink: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    private var displaylink: CADisplayLink?
    private var update: ((TimeInterval) -> Void)?
    
    func start(update: @escaping (TimeInterval) -> Void) {
        self.update = update
        displaylink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(frame))
        displaylink?.add(to: .current, forMode: .default)
    }
    
    func stop() {
        displaylink?.remove(from: .current, forMode: .default)
        update = nil
    }
    
    @objc func frame(displaylink: CADisplayLink) {
        let frameDuration = displaylink.targetTimestamp - displaylink.timestamp
        update?(frameDuration)
    }
}
```

In your swift UI class:

```
@State private var displayLink = DisplayLink()

...

displayLink.start { frameDuration in
    update(frameDuration)
}

...

displayLink.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the replies!

As a result, I came to the conclusion that I left all the work with animation inside the `ObservableObject` class, and in SwiftUI only display based on `@Published` variables. In this way, a clearer division of responsibility has been achieved.